# Selecting the sibling or niece of the loop varaible in "for" loop in XQuery

Tags: xml, loops, xquery

Suppose there is this XML file:

```
<Adam>     
<JackSons>
   <s1>Jack</s1>
   <s2>Sara</s2>
</JackSons>
<PeterSons>
   <s1>Peter</s1>
   <n>
     <s2>Anna</s2>
   </n>
</PeterSons>
<DavidSons>
   <q>
     <s1>David</s1>
   </q>
   <n>
     <s2>Suzann</s2>
   </n>
</DavidSons>
</Adam>
```

I would like to get `s2` which is the sibling or niece of each s1 to call a function on both of them inside the loop, please note we don't know anything about the structure of XML except that each `s1` and `s2` have a common ancestor, I tried

```
let $db := doc('test2.xq')
for $s1 in $db//s1
let $s2 := $db//*[//$s1]/(s2, */s2)


return <p>  {$s1/text()} marry {$s2/text()} </p>
```

It returns

```
<p>Jack marry SaraAnnaSuzann</p>
<p>Peter marry SaraAnnaSuzann</p>
<p>David marry SaraAnnaSuzann</p>
```

I expect

```
<p>Jack marry Sara</p>
<p>Peter marry Anna</p>
<p>David marry Suzann</p>
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve. Adding the expected output might be helpful.

Comment: @JensErat I wrote the expected output

Comment: And why do those get selected? To get this results, you could use `//s2`. You're talking about "I would like to select the parents of each s1 and s2" -- why do you need to do this?

Comment: @JensErat The question is about the loop! and how can I get the sibling of a node when I Iterate over the node, if I can get the right sibling I can get the parent.

Comment: @JensErat I removed the misleading part from the question

Comment: `<..>` is no valid XML tag name, this breaks your input for anybody that tries to build a query for the input given.

Comment: @JensErat By `<..>` I mean it could be anything and one shouldn't rely on it for the answer. Could I say that with better notation? However, if you note to my answer I found the solution (actually with your helps)

Comment: Regarding that notation, we're back to the point of _good questions_. Try to make life easier for those investing their spare time to help you with your problems; provide examples that can be copy-pasted to work with with _minimal effort_. People answering here want to solve _problems_, not deal with messed up syntax in bad, unspecific questions. Good questions will usually get good answers, bad questions none or bad answers.

Comment: @JensErat I should make a tradeoff between not misleading the answerer and providing a working example. (In my previous posts the answerer rely on the structure which was not my intention). How about the changes I made now?!

Comment: @JensErat I just hope one doesn't say `for $pair in Adam/child ...` ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that you search the whole document for `s2` nodes again, not the same item.

Don't search for `s1` elements, but look for pairs and print a message for each of them.

```
for $pair in //item
return <p>{ $pair//s1/text() } marry { $pair//s2/text() }</p>
```

You *could* also look for the `s1` elements and find matching `s2` nodes, but this is harder to read and understand, and pobably performs worse because of descending up back down the tree to find the `item` both belong to:

```
for $s1 in //s1
let $s2 := $s1//ancestor::item//s2
return <p>{ $s1/text() } marry { $s2/text() }</p>
```

In both cases, depending on what's allowed in the document you might want to add some safeguards to only find pairs of two. The probably most restrictive example would be

```
for $pair in //item
let $s1 := $pair//s1, $s2 := $pair//s2
where count($s1) = 1 and count($s2) = 1
return <p>{ $s1/text() } marry { $s2/text() }</p>
```

For completeness, this would even be possible *without* an explicit for loop (while not necessarily being a reasonable solution, as it will get much harder to read and understand if growing in complexity):

```
//item/element p { concat(.//s1/text(), " marry ", .//s2/text()) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but I need to select that in "for"!

Comment: You can always break apart axis steps and use an explicit for loop. `for $item in //item[s1] return $item//s2`. To some extend, axis steps are just implicit for loops.

Comment: I am going to test it in loop, but as I modified my code, i need both s1 and s2 inside the loop to do something with

Comment: based on your suggestion I used `let $db := doc('test2.xq')
for $s1 in $db//s1
let $s2 := $db//*[//s1]/(s2, */s2)


return $s2` but it again return what I posted in my question (9 s2), also please note I don't know if there is `item` node, I just should rely on `s1` and `s2` tags

Comment: I edited my question to convey my purpose better. Hope I have done it

Comment: No, it did not get any clearer at all. Please read [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and try to get in the position of someone else reading your question. Include your requirements, include examples of what to match and what not to match, and explain the rules why. The definition of what items to choose changes with each update of your question. You're tiring those wanting to help with being inspecific and/or repeatedly changing the question!

Comment: No! I didn't ever change my request in this question, maybe I just was misunderstood, without any explanation the title says everything, none of those you posted were in a loop, while `in "for" loop` is a **key point** here, I try to find a solution to convey my meaning

Comment: I revised it again! please note I never changed my request (the title), I just try to clarify it and surprise how you call it ambiguous

Comment: I was close to ignoring the question for its massive amount of changes and refinements, but now that's what a good question should look like. There's a clear problem definitiv with semantics, no hidden requirements hard to get as such in the question title (it was not only me not getting it!) and a clear expected result. With this question asked from the start, we would've saved all the comments and answers not fitting what you've reallly been looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much with your patience and your great help ;)

Comment: Please excuse me, is it possible we do it without referring to `item`? we don't know to which tag s1 and s2 belong! we just know they have a common ancestor. (it was not said explicitly in the revised question, however once I mentioned it and then removed it but it doesn't contradict the question too!)

Comment: This will result in something like `//s1/ancestor::*[.//s2][1]` to find the "items" (first ancestor of s1 elements containing an s2 element), and proceed as before.

Comment: You are right, while the title of question is OK, I made a bad and ambiguous question and that just waste our times (it was a lesson for me). your last suggestion also didn't work. I know you may got tired from this question, but just to make it a worthy question, I revised it another time

Comment: Thank you again very much and excuse me for bothering you, I found a solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30859593/2651073), I am not sure about its logic, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your text's within s1 and s2, something as simple as the following might be enough for you:

```
//item[starts-with(s2, s1)]/s2
```

I would need to see more real data to know if you needed something more complex, however this should work for the examples you have posted.

Comment: Thank  you but my main question is about getting the sibling or niece of a node in a loop

Comment: Placing this in a for loop won't change the results. You will still get the same amount of nodes. XPath and XQuery operate on sequences of nodes. You can try it by rewriting it to `for $s2 in //item[starts-with(s2, s1)]/s2 return $s2` and seeing it gives the same results.

Comment: I got confused, could you please extract both s1 and s2 in a loop and call a function on them?

Comment: `for $item in //item[starts-with(s2, s1)] return some-function($item/s1, $item/s2)`

Answer (score 0):

When you just know the `s1` and `s2` have a common ancestor, you can use the following code:

```
let $db := doc('test2.xq')
for $s1 in $db//s1
   let $item :=  $s1/ancestor::*[.//s1 and .//s2][not(.//*[.//s1 and .//s2])]
   let $s2 := $item//s2
   return <p>{ $s1/text() } marry { $s2/text() }</p>
```

For each `$s1` find an ancestor which contains both `s1` and `s2` of which no descendant contains `s1` and `s2`. This is the first common ancestor (parent). Using this item, find the corresponding (sibling or niece) `s2`.

Comment: Just don't know why `$db//*[.//$s1 and .//s2][not(.//*[.//$s1 and .//s2])]` doesn't work to find the `$item`